# tkinter filedialog window persists after folder selection

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I use the following sub-routine to get a path to the files I require

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog


def get_foldername(prompt):
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()  # get rid of annoying little window
    my_path = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir="/Users/" + getuser(),title=prompt) + "/"
    return my_path
```

The problem is, that the filedialog window persists until the program ends, how can I unload this window before returning to my main program routine?

The following code duplicates the persistence problem:

```
from getpass import getuser
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog


def get_foldername(prompt):
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()  # get rid of annoying little window
    my_path = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir="/Users/" + getuser(), title=prompt) + "/"
    return my_path


def main():
    path_to_files = get_foldername("Choose source folder")
    while True:
        for idx in range(3000000):
            print(path_to_files)
        break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: That is because you have more than one `Tk()` instance in your program. Please remove these 2 lines from your function: `root = Tk()` and `root.withdraw()` and your problem will be fixed.

Comment: It didn't fix it! By removing the two lines as you suggested, I get the annoying little window back and the filedialog still persists until the program has finished. What I need is something to destroy/unload all instances of Tk before returning to the main routine.

Comment: In that case, please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Finally, I don't think there is an answer to this post. It seems not to be a software problem, because if I run the script on my MacBook with Snow Leopard, the persistence problem does not occur, but on my Mac Mini with Yosemite it does! Subject closed!